# Unable to shutdown a thread pool

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I would like to shutdown a server when `countDownLatch.getCount()` is zero, but instead of shutting down, it waits on accepting socket connection. Here is the server code that handles incoming TCP requests.

```
public static void start(File configFile, ReplyListener replyListener, CountDownLatch countDownLatch) {
            try {
                Server.init(configFile);
                while (countDownLatch.getCount() != 0) {
                    //try {
                        Server.socket = serverSocket.accept();
                        Message message = new Message();
                        message.setSocket(Server.socket);
                        Server.pool.submit(new ServerTaskCallable(message.receive()).setReplyListener(replyListener));
                    /*} catch (SocketTimeoutException e){
                        System.out.println("Finished testing");
                    }*/
                }
                Server.socket.close();
                serverSocket.close();
                Server.pool.shutdownNow();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                logger.error("Cannot start a server. The server thread will be terminated. Exception: ", e);
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
```

Here is the thread dum:

```
"pool-1-thread-1@651" prio=5 tid=0xe nid=NA runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
      at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(PlainSocketImpl.java:-1)
      at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:404)
      at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:545)
      at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:513)
      at model.server.Server.start(Server.java:42)
      at model.MainTest.lambda$main$3(MainTest.java:30)
      at model.MainTest$$Lambda$2.2012232625.run(Unknown Source:-1)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
      at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"pool-3-thread-1@1142" prio=5 tid=0x12 nid=NA waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
      at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:-1)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
      at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

How can I terminate properly the server thread pool?

Comment: Did you [set a timeout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#setSoTimeout-int-) on the `ServerSocket`?

Comment: It helped to terminate a thread pool, but I would like to avoid using timeOut() (if it feasible of course).

Comment: I can only think of two options  The first is a timeout, as mentioned, essentially forcing your code through the loop every so often.  The second is to interrupt the thread making the accept call from some master thread.

Comment: Got your ideas. However, I would like to know, why the solution with the countdownLatch doesn't work?

Comment: You cannot interrupt an `accept()` call via `Thread#interrupt()` (since it doesn't throw an `InterruptedException`, thus having nowhere to handle the interruption), although you could `close()` the `ServerSocket` from another thread, which should interrupt the accept

Comment: @Vince Emigh, thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Set a timeout on the `ServerSocket` via [`ServerSocket#setSoTimeout(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#setSoTimeout-int-). This will cause `accept()` to throw a `SocketTimeoutException` everytime the timeout occurs. You will need to catch the exception *inside* your loop to ensure your server keeps listening for connections:

   ```
   while(countDownLatch.getCount() != 0) {
       try {
           socket = serverSocket.accept();
       } catch(SocketTimeoutException e) {
         //timeout occurred!
       }
   }
   ```
2. Close the `ServerSocket` via [`ServerSocket#close()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#close--) from a different thread. This will throw a `SocketAcception`,  terminating the `accept()` call. This exception could be caught *outside* the loop to easily exit the "listen for connections" behavior.